# Sorting integers in a file without using collections java

Tags: java, file, sorting, io, randomaccessfile

I need to sort integers in a file without using an array/arraylist. The file has to be read using RandomAccessFile. I can't think of any approach to solve this other than using an arraylist. I am allowed to use a few variables. Also, how do i swap two numbers in a file?

```
import java.io.*;

class Sort
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try {
            RandomAccessFile abc = new RandomAccessFile(args[0], "rw");
            long n = abc.length();
            System.out.println(n);
            long i = 0;
            while (i <= n) {
                System.out.println("Coming Here");
                int c = Integer.parseInt(abc.readUTF());
                System.out.println(c);
                i = i + 1;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Did you check the documentation? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html

Comment: A [`RandomAccessFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) is basically an array on disk, so just treat it as such.

Comment: @AdrianK. I've got till reading the integers from the file and writing them back. I am unable to figure out how i can sort the numbers without using another data structure. The documentation didn't really help.

Comment: Then please provide your code too.
Also, how were you able to read the documentation in 2 minutes?

Comment: @AdrianK. I read the documentation a few hours back. It didn't help which is why I came here.

Comment: Okay, sorry then. But still - please show us your code.

Comment: What format is this file supposed to be in?

Comment: Your input file actually has characters in it or binary data?

Comment: @SeanBright Character data

Comment: Kinda funny, looks like a whole bunch of people have the same problem (test?!) right now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40494501/java-file-handling-please-its-important-i-tried-solving-it-but-couldnt-get-th

Comment: Based on the linked question, it should not contain characters, but binary data instead. You most likely should be using `readInt()` and not `readUTF8`.

Comment: @GhostCat Yeah, kind of. But I actually tried solving this

Comment: @SeanBright okay. I'll try that .How do I sort the numbers after reading the data?

Comment: @Siddhartharao - the same way you sort an array, `array[i]` === `file.seek(i * 4); file.readInt()`

Comment: @SeanBright I will try doing that. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the task would be difficult when the integers where text in the file, due to varying lengths of textual number representations.

- First it should be checked that the data is binary.

So I'll assume that binary data, containing `int` is stored in the file.
A java `int` occupies 4 bytes, so every file position will be a four fold.

So you could use **arrays**. If an array for all, `Arrays.sort` would solve it. Otherwise several arrays and a **merge sort** algorithm would be feasible.

Staying with a random access file you could do quicksort or merge sort using:

```
fh.seek(i1*4L);
int n1 = fh.readInt();
// If ints are not stored in big endian byte order:
// int n1littleEndian = Integer.reverse(n1);
```

In production environment, one would get the associated channel, and use a memory mapped byte buffer; to  speed up things.

Comment: I want to sort the integers within the file itself and that too, without using arrays